# How do I check if a user-inputted character and string is found in a randomly selected phrase?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a for loop that will search through a given string to see if it matches the what the user has input. This could be a character or string, but not both. What I was trying to make at first was the check for the character. However this little snippet of code accomplishes the opposite and works as a check for the string.

```
    Scanner guessInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    StringBuilder hPhrase = new StringBuilder("Hello World");
    int pLength = hPhrase.length();
    String aGuess = guessInput.nextLine();
    char chGuess = aGuess.charAt(0); //it's zero here as a placeholder, just so it can run.
    
    for(int x = 0; x < pLength; x++){
        if(chGuess == (hPhrase.charAt(x))){
            System.out.println("it worked");
        }else{
            System.out.println("it didn't work");
         }
    }
```

How would I check if a character the user inputs is found in the string?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but why not use [String::contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat YES. That's exactly it.